# Date-Time searching in VB.NET displays no result

Tags: vb.net, datepicker

I have a problem with search form. I use date-time picker for user to pickup their prefer date. And when I tried to set any date, it produces no result. Bellow is my code:

```
Try
     myDataSet.Clear()
     myCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblVisitor WHERE EnterDate LIKE @EnterDate", myConnection)
     myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EnterDate", DateTime.Parse(cboEnterDate.Text))
     myAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(myCommand)
     myAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "tblVisitor")
     dgvVisitor.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables(0)
 Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
 End Try
```

And when I pick one date from the date-time picker, it displays nothing beside the blank data grid view, even that date is available in the database.

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: I believe that you have two problems:  1.  LIKE is used for matching character string against patterns so I'm not sure it works with Date columns.  2.  I don't believe that you can use a parameter with the LIKE clause in that manner.

Comment: Your code looks like you're actually using a combobox for selecting the date, not a date-time picker (which doesn't have a Text property).

Comment: What data type is EnterDate in tblVisitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates are not strings. You should not use the LIKE operator. Typically you will want to use the BETWEEN operator when searching for dates.

Example:

```
Try
     myDataSet.Clear()
     myCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblVisitor WHERE EnterDate BETWEEN @EnterDate AND DATEADD(dd, 1, @EnterDate)", myConnection)
     myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EnterDate", DateTime.Parse(cboEnterDate.Text))
     myAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(myCommand)
     myAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "tblVisitor")
     dgvVisitor.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables(0)
 Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
 End Try
```

Comment: But I want user to search for specific date. How should I do?

Comment: Assuming the date is just the date (no time), just add 1 to it for the second parameter and you will get all the records for that date.

Comment: If you are really paranoid about EnterDate landing exactly at midnight, change the ending of the BETWEEN clause to:
 dateadd(s, -1, dateadd(dd, 1, @EnterDate))

Comment: @Bill - it would probably be better to just remove the time portion from the date, like this: DateTime.Parse(cboEnterDate.Text).Date.

Comment: @Brian: problem is not with the input from the client. Problem is with the database. If you have a record stored on EnterDate+1 at exactly midnight, it will be included in the BETWEEN date and date + 1. Probably won't happen, but I hate probably.

Comment: @Bill, according to the MS documentation, the BETWEEN expression includes the end values. So, if the date you were testing landed on exactly midnight, it should be returned correctly. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx